# Matlab figure always visible

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wrote a matlab function that does a lot of things on a figure.

Now, the problem is the figure is NOT displayed until the program terminates its execution, but I would want the figure to be displayed, in realtime, with all modifications, and always in the foreground, while the program progresses.

How I can do this? `figure('visible','on')` does not sort any effect, nor set() command.

Code snippet:

```
set(gcf,'visible','on')
parfor (i=1:n, 8)

    if norm(A(i,:))<1
        countr=countr+1;
    end
    hold on;
    plot(A(i,1),A(i,2),'+')

end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend it, but I think you need to add some `drawnow` statements, it will sync the visual and calculation thread.

Comment: Thanks, with drawnow I got the desired result. Unfortunately, it slow *much* the execution.. There is any other way?

Comment: @user2157783 That's the reason I did not recommend it, your calculation has to wait for the graphics to be finished. Can't you add a counter such that the `drawnow` is executed once every 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the figure must be visible; otherwise you should modify this property. Thus, try to look for any code that includes `wait`. 
Other option is to try `figure(gcf)` to bring the focus to the figure you want.

Comment: Not sure if it really fits my purpose, but I'll do some research about wait statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The statement `figure('visible','on')` creates a **new** figure, but you want to make the already existing one visible, thus use:

```
set(gcf,'visible','on')
```

**EDIT 2**

I cannot reproduce the issue (probably the example is not a good one):

```
A = rand(100,2);
set(gcf,'visible','on')
hold on
parfor (i=1:100, 8)
        plot(A(i,1),A(i,2),'+')
        pause(0.01)
end
```

**OLD EDIT** Parfor and graphics (source "[How to see plots during parfor](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/294212)"):

According to the source, the quick answer is you cannot update the screen output within the `parfor` but with the `drawnow` which defies the purpose of the parfor. Therefore, do you strictly need the parfor?

However, see my **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with set(), figure is created at the very beginning and stays in foreground, but nothing is drawn until the algorithm terminates its execution.

Comment: Of course, you need to include that statement inside your algorithm.
You can access the code with `edit yourfunction` at which point it would be easy to locate a potential statement that sets the figure to invisible and comment it out.

Comment: Perhaps I was too vague, I will be more precise: A 'plot(something)' statement is executed for every iteration of a *for* loop. I require the figure to stand in foreground and to be upgraded at every iteration. Now, I placed the set() statement just before the for loop, in my code, but the problem persists. Also, AFAIK, there is no statement in my code that makes figure invisible... Thanks again.

Comment: Then instead of plotting every time you should refresh the data: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/data_analysis/making-graphs-responsive-with-data-linking.html.
Also, if you could post a snippet of code it would help.

Comment: I edited the original post, being difficult to quote code in comments. Thanks!

Comment: Parfor lowers execution time by a factor of 2.5x on my quadcore system. It is not strictly needed, but it's useful :) What is the minimum value I can pass to pause()?

Comment: Should be 1/100 of a second. I would also try `drawnow expose` which refreshes only graphical object. It might be faster. Ultimately, you can try to time what are the bottlenecks inside the parfor, and we might try to optimize that and swtich to simple loop at the same time.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you updated your question with the working solution, because it's not clear what you adopted.

Comment: I really found all answers to be useful. Do you mind if I vote Nick? It was the very first I found fitting my needs. Thanks!